# The "if" condition in "set" method isn't working

Tags: java, class, oop, object

So which floor the lift is on should be able to be read and changed, but only within the allowed range for just that house the lift is installed in. I'm trying to get an "If" condition working looking for a boolean true value from method "validFloor".

Based on my very beginner knowledge of Java, I assume putting an "If" condition in the set-method is a proper attempt?

```
private int currentFloor = 0;
private int numberOfFloors;
private boolean validFloor = false;

public Elevator(int numberOfFloors) {
    this.numberOfFloors = numberOfFloors;
}

//Sets the allowed number of floors (0 to 100)
public void allowedNumberOfFloors() {
    if (numberOfFloors < 2) {
        numberOfFloors = 2;
    } else if (numberOfFloors > 100) {
        numberOfFloors = 100;
    }
}

//Checks validity of the elevator floor in relation to total floors.
public void validFloor() {
    if (currentFloor > numberOfFloors && currentFloor < 0) {
        this.validFloor = false;
    }
}

//Checks whether the specified floor is in reasonable range.
public void setFloor(int currentFloor) {
    if (validFloor) {
        this.currentFloor = currentFloor;
    }
}

public int getFloor() {
    return currentFloor;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Number of floors: " + numberOfFloors + "\nCurrent floor: " + currentFloor;
}
```

For example, if you try to move the lift to floor 74 in a house that only has 5 floors, it should not work. I want the hiss to start at bottom floor 0, hence the 0 value in class variable "currentFloor".

The If condition in the "validFloor" method doesn't seem to be recognized at all. Instead all that matters is the boolean value I put on the class variable validFloor.

Comment: You newer call the method validFloor(), you just read the boolean variable.

Comment: Check your logical expression: is it even possible?

Comment: Why do you have a member `validFloor` as well as a `validFloor` method?

Comment: The `validFloor` method should probably take a parameter (the floor number to be checked). And the setter should probably throw an Exception instead of just doing nothing when the number is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call the `validFloor()` method, so the value of `validFloor` is never changed.  Also, you code never sets `validFloor` to true anywhere, so it wouldn't even matter if you called `validFloor()`, because it can only set `validFloor` to `false`, or leave it at the initial value of `false`.

The "correct" way to do something like this is:

```
public boolean isValidFloor(floor) {
  // It seems weird to me that 0 is a valid floor.  Is that correct?
  // If floors are zero-indexed, the top floor should actually be numberOfFloors-1.
  return floor >= 0 && floor <= this.numberOfFloors;
}

public void setFloor(int newFloor) {
    if (isValidFloor(newFloor)) {
        this.currentFloor = newFloor;
    }
}
```

Notice that there's no need to even keep around a `validFloor` variable.  We can just check whether or not a floor is valid every time we need to without saving the result.